Bluesky のドキュメントの画面で「SEND API REQUEST」を実行してもアカウント user 情報が取得できない
最終的にやりたいことは、BLUESKY_HANDLE と BLUESKY_APP_PASSWORD から user情報を取得です。
app.bsky.actor.getProfileの左側にある例の下にあるREQUESTの部分で「Bearer Token」と「HANDLE」を入力後、「API REQUEST BUTTON」を押してもRESPONSEに "Cannot GET /xrpc" と表示され、ユーザー情報を取得できません。このページのREQUESTの部分は正常に動作していますか？

ドキュメントの不具合で語彙(lexicon)の部分が省略されてしまっています。本来のURLはxrpcの後ろに/app.bsky.actor.getProfile等が続くべきですが、各言語の例も遊び場もその部分が省略された間違ったURLになっています。そのため、正しいURLに自分で保管しない限り、サンプルやプレイグラウンドは正しく動作することはありません。
この不具合は下記のIssueで報告されています。修正状況についてはそちらを追ってください。
API Playground has the lexicon name omitted · Issue #105 · bluesky-social/bsky-docs · GitHub
なお、これは例や遊び場だけの問題であり、ドキュメントに記載されているURLは正しいようですので、ドキュメントのみを参考に実装してください。
